# Cannot get Angular scope data in Laravel Blade view

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I am new to Angular. I am trying to get data from the Angular controller into Laravel Blade. For some reason it is not working.

The `socket.io` part is working. I did `console.log` on `$scope.message` and it is there.

So the problem is between Angular code and Laravel blade. My code is:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<input id="auth_id"  type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" />
<h1>New Users</h1>
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
    @{{ message.body }}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/socket.io.js') }}"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope){
        var socket = io('http://192.168.10.10:3000');
        $scope.id = document.getElementById('auth_id').value;
        socket.on("user."+ $scope.id + ":App\\Events\\EventDeletedOrEditedBroadcast", function(data) {
            $scope.messages = data.message;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the data called by the socket.on needs to be returned to $scope outside this method. I just don't know how

Answer (score 0):

the variable you declare in the scope is not the same that wich you want to acces

$scope.messages

@{{message}}

that S

Comment: I believe the `message` refers to the ng-repeat message

Answer (score 0):

This issue is with the Binding; Make sure *messages* is in the $scope.

Check: `<input type="text" ng-model="test">`

In the controller:

**$scope.test = data.message(any string);**

If it works then there is definitely a binding issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know is kind of an old question and I am pretty new to all this stuff (laravel, angular, etc) but I think what you were looking for was this:

In order to get the angular scope working here

```
   <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
@{{ message.body }}
</li>
```

and since the "{{" "}}" is used by laravel, you have to define another way to get the scope, by using $interpolateProvider, like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(config);
config.$inject = ['$interpolateProvider'];
function config($interpolateProvider){

$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<<');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('>>');
}
```

so, then, you change the @{{

```
<li ng-repeat="message in messages">
<< message.body >>
</li>
```

Hope it helps someone